# Trying to use Apache Gobblin to read Salesforce data using SOAP API(s) instead of REST API

Tags: java, rest, soap, gobblin

I am working on an existing tool (heavily based on `Apache Gobblin`) to import data from customers' Salesforce tables into local MySQL databases (one database per customer).

The tool works (as is) for customers who have enabled the Salesforce REST APIs, but one customer does not (and will not) have it enabled, only allowing access to Salesforce via the Salesforce SOAP APIs.

Is it possible to indicate to Gobblin that the data needs to be imported (extracted) from Salesforce using the Salesforce SOAP Apis?  (The existing `SalesforceExtractor` class  `extends RestApiExtractor`; there's no existing `SoapApiExtractor` to inherit from.

Has anyone added classes to Gobblin to allow it to extract from Salesforce over SOAP, to work this way?

The existing Gobblin documentation indicates that it *can* work that way, but I don't see the source code that does it.

Comment: I listed Java as a tag, but forgot to mention - the tool is entirely written in Java, and any new code must also be written in Java.

Comment: I've never seen SF instance where SOAP API is available but REST isn't ;) This is technical block (how?) or client just is opposed to REST in general?

Comment: Salesforce customers have the ability to enable or disable each API.  This customer has SOAP API enabled, but not the REST API.   I was able to write code to convert from the SOAP representation of a SObject and of a QueryResult to the REST equialents.  A few hundred lines of calling the appropriate "set" and "get" functions, but it works (despite being ugly).

Answer (score -1):

I basically wrote about 250 lines of calling SOAP object getters feeding their results to REST object setters.  Very similar names (for the most part) and rather ugly code, but it works.